# Pod install doesn't download frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm using swift and pods. When I type 'pod install' on my terminal, instead of having the frameworks downloaded to my project, I get the files.

This makes no difference to me, except for the fact that when I want to import them in my project, I always get an error saying they can't be found.
Here is my pod file

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'Project' do

    pod 'MSSTabbedPageViewController'
    pod 'PageMenu'

end
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to open the workspace or project?

Comment: Is the name of your target actually `Project`? If not, change that to the actual target name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ocarol stated, import the framework. However, **before** importing at the top of the file you want to use the framework, **build the project**, as Xcode seems to not link the pod's to the project automatically.

Also open the `.xcworkspace` file that pod install generates.

Answer (score -1):

You use these libraries as frameworks (use_frameworks!). So you have to `import` the framework at the top of the Swift file, like:

```
import MSSTabbedPageViewController
```

if had created a bridging header file, you can `import` the framework in it.